# How to extract just the specific directory from a zip archive in C# .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, compression, zip

I have zip file with following internal structure:

```
file1.txt
directoryABC
    fileA.txt
    fileB.txt
    fileC.txt
```

What would be the best way to extract files from "directoryABC" folder to a target location on hard drive? For example if target location is "C:\temp" then its content should be:

```
temp
    directoryABC
        fileA.txt
        fileB.txt
        fileC.txt
```

Also in certain situations I'd want to extract only content of the "directoryABC" so the result would be:

```
temp
    fileA.txt
    fileB.txt
    fileC.txt
```

How can I accomplish this by using classes from System.IO.Compression in C# .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is another version to extract the files of a named directory to the target directory...

```
class Program
{
    static object lockObj = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string zipPath = @"C:\Temp\Test\Test.zip";
        string extractPath = @"c:\Temp\xxx";
        string directory = "testabc";
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        {
            var result = from currEntry in archive.Entries
                         where Path.GetDirectoryName(currEntry.FullName) == directory
                         where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currEntry.Name)
                         select currEntry;


            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in result)
            {
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.Name));
            }
        } 
    }        
}
```

Comment: Be aware that in order tu use `ZipFile` the using is `System.IO.Compression` but the assembly needed is `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) states it properly but I had troubles finding this.