# C# - extract specific directory from ZIP, preserving folder structure

Tags: c#, .net, zip, compression

I have a zip archive and the folder structure inside of an archive looks something like this:

```
+ dirA
  - fileA.txt
  + dirB
    - fileB.txt
```

I'm trying to extract the contents of `dirA` to disk, but while doing so, I'm unable to perserve the folder structure, and instead of

```
  - fileA.txt
  + dirB
    - fileB.txt
```

I get

```
  - fileA.txt
  - fileB.txt
```

Here's my code:

```cs
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(archivePath)) // archivePath is path to the zip archive
{
    // get the root directory
    var root = archive.Entries[0]?.FullName;
    if (root == null) { 
        // quit in a nice way
    }
    var result = from curr in archive.Entries
                 where Path.GetDirectoryName(curr.FullName) != root
                 where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(curr.Name)
                 select curr;

    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in result)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.Name); // extractPath is somwhere on the disk
        entry.ExtractToFile(path);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty positive that's because I use `entry.Name` instead of `entry.FullName` in `Path.Combine()`, but if I were to use `FullName`, I would have in path that root directory `dirA` I'm trying not to extract. 
So I've hit a wall here, and the only solution I can think of is extracting the whole zip with:

```cs
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archivePath, extractPath);
```

...and then moving the subfolders from `dirA` to a different location and deleting `dirA`. Which doesn't seem like the luckiest of ideas.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: **See Also**: [How to extract just the specific directory from a zip archive in C# .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22133053/1366033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just shorten the FullName by the part of the path you dont want:

```
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in result)
{
    var newName = entry.FullName.Substring(root.Length);
    string path = Path.Combine(extractPath, newName);

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

    entry.ExtractToFile(path);
}
```

Comment: Why, that's a great workaround and it seems so perfectly obvious now! Thanks.